# How to concatenate two github files using a Shell Script command

Tags: shell, github, jenkins

As part of jenkins I want to concatenate two github files using the Shell script command

```
cat https://www.github.com/tree/master/app/file1 >> https://www.github.com/tree/master/app/src/file2
```

I tried the file path urls but I get below error

> No such file or directory

- I double checked the path to the files and they exist.
- I also tried this command in local (I use mac), but gets the same error

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete, self-contained example showing that your command works fine exactly as posted:

First, we can create two test files:

```
$ echo "First file" > file1
$ echo "Second file" > file2
```

And verify that they exist and are readable in the current directory:

```
$ ls -l file1 file2
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser  mygroup  11 Jul  5 14:09 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser  mygroup  12 Jul  5 14:09 file2
```

Now we can append `file1` to `file2` with your command, which completes silently without error

```
$ cat file1 >> file2
```

Now we can examine `file2` to verify that it worked, which it did:

```
$ cat file2
Second file
First file
```

If this is not what you do or it's not working for you, please edit your question and update it with the code that you **actually run** along with all error messages copy-pasted (not transcribed, paraphrased, translated or edited).